# Exiting UI Router active state when dismissing modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the [Angular UI modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs) with UI Router. When I cancel the modal, the state does not exit. Instead, it remains active. If I delete or save the modal, the state is properly exited. Any suggestions on how to exit the modal state when simply dismissing the modal?

Router

```
.state('selection.edit', {

    url: '/edit/:projectId',

    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function ($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {

       $modal.open({

      templateUrl: 'app/views/detail.html',

      controller: 'EditProjectCtrl as editProject'
    })
    .result.finally(function () {
      $state.go('selection');
    });
  }]
 })
```

Controller:

```
editProject.cancel = function () {
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

  // State still remains active here
 };

editProject.destroy = function () {
  $modalInstance.close(editProject.selected);
  editProject.project.$remove(editProject.project).then(function (data) {
   });
};

editProject.save = function () {
  $modalInstance.close(editProject.selected);
  editProject.project.$save(editProject.project).then(function (data) {

    // . . .
  });
};
```